# unknown variable 'lower_case_table_names=1'

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu, my.cnf, case-sensitive

I want enable lowercase table names so i have added to `etc/mysql/my.cnf` also `etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf`

```
lower_case_table_name = 1
```

restart the service `sudo service mysql restart`
I can acces service from phpmyadmin, but I can't access it from cli

```
$ mysql -u root -p
mysql: unknown variable 'lower_case_table_names=1'
```

how to enabled lowercase table name correctly?

environment

- OS: ubuntu 20.04
- Mariadb: 10.5.9-MariaDB-1:10.5.9+maria~focal

**updated:**

my.cnf

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# If you are new to MariaDB, check out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-mariadb-articles/

#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 lower_case_table_names = 1

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

mariadb.cnf

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# If you are new to MariaDB, check out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-mariadb-articles/

#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 lower_case_table_names = 1

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Comment: In which config file section did you add this variable?

Comment: As @mustaccio is hinting at, this variable must be under the `[mariadb]` section, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @mustaccio I was update question, that's my `my.cnf` and `mariadb.cnf`

Comment: @matigo I can't see `[mariadb]` section in both cnf files

Comment: Well, you can't just sprinkle configuration variables at will, each belongs to a certain section (scope); if it's not there, you have to add one.

Comment: @mustaccio You was save my day

Comment: _Changing_ the value of that setting is asking for a world of hurt.  Moving inconsistently cased table names from Windows (which does not care) to Linux (which treats them as different) is not easy.

Answer (score 3):

You have misplaced your setting; `lower_case_table_names` belongs to the `[mariadb]` section, as shown [in the docs](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/lower_case_table_names/). If the section is missing, you simply need to add it.

You also should get rid of a duplicate configuration file; one is sufficient, and having two will get you more grief in the future.

---

If you want to understand better what's wrong, read this section of the template configuration file:

```
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
```

`lower_case_table_names` is a *server-side* setting and it obviously confuses the client, `mysql`. phpMyAdmin does not know or care about the MariaDB configuration files, so it doesn't see the setting.